# Ionic Remote Access Error

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, remote-access

I'm getting the error below, on ionic serve:

Argument of type '(res: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type
                'PartialObserver'. Type '(res: Response) => void' is not assignable to type
                'CompletionObserver'. Property 'complete' is missing in type '(res: Response) => void'.

```
ts code is as follows:
return  this.http.get(this.getApiUrl)
            .do((res : Response ) => console.log(res.json()))
            .map((res : Response ) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you import response? import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';